# Python: Exception has occurred: ReadTimeout - Pattern not detected: '[>#]' in output

Tags: python, netmiko

I try to connect on WLC device. My code works on other devices except for this one. I can't connect on it. Here is my code and I also attached a grab-shot for the error.

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
 
with ConnectHandler(host = '<ip_address>',
                        port = 22,
                        username = '<_username>',
                        password = '<_password>',
                        device_type = 'cisco_wlc_ssh') as ch:
print(ch.send_command("show version"))
```

[image: Error Details]

Comment: Check if the shell prompt for the device was changed to something other than > or #. For eg., it could be a $

Comment: how to check this one?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current prompt string, and then use it to provide an expected termination character. For eg. try something like this.

```
with ConnectHandler(host='<ip_address>',
                    port=22,
                    username='<_username>',
                    password='<_password>',
                    device_type='cisco_wlc_ssh') as ch:
    device_prompt = ch.find_prompt()
    print(device_prompt) #- Check this, this is the expected termination string.

    # This is a fix - on assumption, to use the last character in the prompt
    ch.send_command('show version', expect_string=device_prompt[-1])
```

The `expect_string` attrib can help you in setting the termination character. That must be relative to the prompt in the client shell.

Comment: Hi Kris, thanks for your response but still I get same error.

Comment: What was the device prompt you got ?

Comment: I use VS Code and run it on Python Debug Console